# How to understand this raw HTML of Yahoo! Finance when retrieving data using Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, yahoo-finance

I've been trying to retrieve stock price from Yahoo! Finance, like for [Apple Inc.](http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL). My code is like this:(using Python 2)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL'
r = requests.get(html)
soup = bs(r.text)
```

The problem is when I see raw HTML behind this webpage, the class is dynamic, see figure below. This makes it hard for BeautifulSoup to get tags. How to understand the class and how to get data?

[HTML of Yahoo! Finance page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bITK0.png)

PS: 1) I know pandas_datareader.data, but that's for historical data. I want the real-time stock data;

2) I don't want to use selenium to open a new browser window.

Answer (score 8):

The  data is obviously populated using *reactjs* so you won't be able to parse it reliably using class names etc.. You can get all the data in *json* format from the page source from the `root.App.main` script :

```
import  requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from json import loads

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL").content)
script = soup.find("script",text=re.compile("root.App.main")).text
data = loads(re.search("root.App.main\s+=\s+(\{.*\})", script).group(1))
print(data)
```

Which gives you a whole load of json, you can go through the data and pick what you need like below :

```
stores = data["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]
from  pprint import pprint as pp

pp(stores[u'QuoteSummaryStore'])
```

Which gives you:

```
{u'price': {u'averageDailyVolume10Day': {u'fmt': u'63.06M',
                                         u'longFmt': u'63,056,525',
                                         u'raw': 63056525},
            u'averageDailyVolume3Month': {u'fmt': u'36.53M',
                                          u'longFmt': u'36,527,196',
                                          u'raw': 36527196},
            u'currency': u'USD',
            u'currencySymbol': u'$',
            u'exchange': u'NMS',
            u'exchangeName': u'NasdaqGS',
            u'longName': u'Apple Inc.',
            u'marketState': u'PRE',
            u'maxAge': 1,
            u'openInterest': {},
            u'postMarketChange': {u'fmt': u'0.11', u'raw': 0.11000061},
            u'postMarketChangePercent': {u'fmt': u'0.10%',
                                         u'raw': 0.0009687416},
            u'postMarketPrice': {u'fmt': u'113.66', u'raw': 113.66},
            u'postMarketSource': u'DELAYED',
            u'postMarketTime': 1474502277,
            u'preMarketChange': {u'fmt': u'0.42', u'raw': 0.41999817},
            u'preMarketChangePercent': {u'fmt': u'0.37%',
                                        u'raw': 0.0036987949},
            u'preMarketPrice': {u'fmt': u'113.97', u'raw': 113.97},
            u'preMarketSource': u'FREE_REALTIME',
            u'preMarketTime': 1474536411,
            u'quoteType': u'EQUITY',
            u'regularMarketChange': {u'fmt': u'-0.02', u'raw': -0.019996643},
            u'regularMarketChangePercent': {u'fmt': u'-0.02%',
                                            u'raw': -0.00017607327},
            u'regularMarketDayHigh': {u'fmt': u'113.99', u'raw': 113.989},
            u'regularMarketDayLow': {u'fmt': u'112.44', u'raw': 112.441},
            u'regularMarketOpen': {u'fmt': u'113.82', u'raw': 113.82},
            u'regularMarketPreviousClose': {u'fmt': u'113.57',
                                            u'raw': 113.57},
            u'regularMarketPrice': {u'fmt': u'113.55', u'raw': 113.55},
            u'regularMarketSource': u'FREE_REALTIME',
            u'regularMarketTime': 1474488000,
            u'regularMarketVolume': {u'fmt': u'31.57M',
                                     u'longFmt': u'31,574,028.00',
                                     u'raw': 31574028},
            u'shortName': u'Apple Inc.',
            u'strikePrice': {},
            u'symbol': u'AAPL',
            u'underlyingSymbol': None},
 u'price,summaryDetail': {},
 u'quoteType': {u'exchange': u'NMS',
                u'headSymbol': None,
                u'longName': u'Apple Inc.',
                u'market': u'us_market',
                u'messageBoardId': u'finmb_24937',
                u'quoteType': u'EQUITY',
                u'shortName': u'Apple Inc.',
                u'symbol': u'AAPL',
                u'underlyingExchangeSymbol': None,
                u'underlyingSymbol': None,
                u'uuid': u'8b10e4ae-9eeb-3684-921a-9ab27e4d87aa'},
 u'summaryDetail': {u'ask': {u'fmt': u'114.00', u'raw': 114},
                    u'askSize': {u'fmt': u'100',
                                 u'longFmt': u'100',
                                 u'raw': 100},
                    u'averageDailyVolume10Day': {u'fmt': u'63.06M',
                                                 u'longFmt': u'63,056,525',
                                                 u'raw': 63056525},
                    u'averageVolume': {u'fmt': u'36.53M',
                                       u'longFmt': u'36,527,196',
                                       u'raw': 36527196},
                    u'averageVolume10days': {u'fmt': u'63.06M',
                                             u'longFmt': u'63,056,525',
                                             u'raw': 63056525},
                    u'beta': {u'fmt': u'1.52', u'raw': 1.51744},
                    u'bid': {u'fmt': u'113.68', u'raw': 113.68},
                    u'bidSize': {u'fmt': u'400',
                                 u'longFmt': u'400',
                                 u'raw': 400},
                    u'dayHigh': {u'fmt': u'113.99', u'raw': 113.989},
                    u'dayLow': {u'fmt': u'112.44', u'raw': 112.441},
                    u'dividendRate': {u'fmt': u'2.28', u'raw': 2.28},
                    u'dividendYield': {u'fmt': u'2.01%', u'raw': 0.0201},
                    u'exDividendDate': {u'fmt': u'2016-08-04',
                                        u'raw': 1470268800},
                    u'expireDate': {},
                    u'fiftyDayAverage': {u'fmt': u'108.61',
                                         u'raw': 108.608284},
                    u'fiftyTwoWeekHigh': {u'fmt': u'123.82', u'raw': 123.82},
                    u'fiftyTwoWeekLow': {u'fmt': u'89.47', u'raw': 89.47},
                    u'fiveYearAvgDividendYield': {},
                    u'forwardPE': {u'fmt': u'12.70', u'raw': 12.701344},
                    u'marketCap': {u'fmt': u'611.86B',
                                   u'longFmt': u'611,857,399,808',
                                   u'raw': 611857399808},
                    u'maxAge': 1,
                    u'navPrice': {},
                    u'open': {u'fmt': u'113.82', u'raw': 113.82},
                    u'openInterest': {},
                    u'payoutRatio': {u'fmt': u'24.80%', u'raw': 0.248},
                    u'previousClose': {u'fmt': u'113.57', u'raw': 113.57},
                    u'priceToSalesTrailing12Months': {u'fmt': u'2.78',
                                                      u'raw': 2.777534},
                    u'regularMarketDayHigh': {u'fmt': u'113.99',
                                              u'raw': 113.989},
                    u'regularMarketDayLow': {u'fmt': u'112.44',
                                             u'raw': 112.441},
                    u'regularMarketOpen': {u'fmt': u'113.82', u'raw': 113.82},
                    u'regularMarketPreviousClose': {u'fmt': u'113.57',
                                                    u'raw': 113.57},
                    u'regularMarketVolume': {u'fmt': u'31.57M',
                                             u'longFmt': u'31,574,028',
                                             u'raw': 31574028},
                    u'strikePrice': {},
                    u'totalAssets': {},
                    u'trailingAnnualDividendRate': {u'fmt': u'2.13',
                                                    u'raw': 2.13},
                    u'trailingAnnualDividendYield': {u'fmt': u'1.88%',
                                                     u'raw': 0.018754954},
                    u'trailingPE': {u'fmt': u'13.24', u'raw': 13.240438},
                    u'twoHundredDayAverage': {u'fmt': u'102.39',
                                              u'raw': 102.39367},
                    u'volume': {u'fmt': u'31.57M',
                                u'longFmt': u'31,574,028',
                                u'raw': 31574028},
                    u'yield': {},
                    u'ytdReturn': {}},
 u'symbol': u'AAPL'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by 'dynamic' in this case, but have you considered using CSS selectors?

With Beautifulsoup you could get it e.g like this:

```
soup.select('div#quote-header-info section span')[0]
```

And there are some variations you could use on the pattern, such as using the '>' filter.

You could get the same with just `lxml`, no need for BeautifulSoup:

```
import lxml.html as html
page = html.parse(url).getroot()
content = page.cssselect('div#quote-header-info section > span:first-child')[0].text
```

Which immediately illustrates a more specific selector.

If you're interested in more efficient DOM-traversal, research xpaths.

Comment: They mean dynamic as in the content is loaded with Javascript/react which you could see if you looked at the html. They are not asking how to use selectors, they are asking how to parse dynamic content.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham While I agree it is often far better to find the data in alternative forms (usually loaded from some json), that does not mean the data cannot be mined using other methods, such as the one I proposed which works as well, because it doesn't rely on tag attributes. your assumption I did not look at the source is presumptuous.  While you may find my answer not useful and downvote it for that reason, others may find it useful so I'll let it stand. Note that I don't hold it against you, I upvoted your answer because I find it is more complete.

Comment: The first comment is just what I meant. @Oliver W. your answer is correct, just I don't understand why use 'div#quote-header-info section span' will work. Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: @artmunich It works because you don't depend on any of the dynamically generated attributes (the values of the `class` and `data-reactid` in this case). You're only counting on the nesting of the tags (a `span` that is inside a `section` which is itself in a `div` with a specific `id`), which many websites define upfront, as a sort of template/skeleton/model that later on could get altered dynamically. Not every website does it this way, some even produce that template dynamically, but finance.yahoo is one of those websites that makes the template in a static way.