# Learning web scraping. I get an error of 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when trying to retrieve text in an element

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, stock

Code: https://pastebin.com/JeifRAyT

```
def FetchPrice():
    URLForStock = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(URLForStock.text, "html5lib")
    Price=soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'}).text
    return Price
```

Page I'm trying to scrape off of: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT

The element I am trying to retrieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gkGN.jpg

Here's what the HTML looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gASc4.jpg

I don't get what's wrong with line 4. I have it looking for a span. I also have the class I'm looking for. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of -:
you can look below to find the answer

[How to understand this raw HTML of Yahoo! Finance when retrieving data using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631386/how-to-understand-this-raw-html-of-yahoo-finance-when-retrieving-data-using-pyt)

Comment: #Price = soup.find('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}).find('span').text


This line I found finds it. I don't understand why it has to refer to a div that's it's parent in order to get the text I need.