# How do I extract a specific field from Yahoo Finance using Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I want to extract the share float of a company. Please see this link as an example:
view-source:https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GE/key-statistics

I can see that the raw data in floatShares is what I want to get to:

```
"floatShares":{"raw":8733446536,"fmt":"8.73B","longFmt":"8,733,446,536"}
```

However, when I use BeautifulSoup, it is not able to locate this information even though I can find it using `ctrl-F`. Can anyone advise how I can capture the numeric data `8733446536` in a variable called `floatShares` using Python/BeautifulSoup?

Thanks

Comment: Show us what have you tried until now

Comment: The JSON data you found in the page source seems to be within the javascript `<script>` tag. You could use BeautifulSoup to extract out the content of the script, but will need something else in order to extract/parse/execute the javascript code to get the particular line you are after.

Comment: You could use [this](http://www.compjour.org/warmups/govt-text-releases/intro-to-bs4-lxml-parsing-wh-press-briefings/#extracting-attributes-from-a-tag-with-attrs) to get & parse the data.

Comment: I did not post the code because I simply do not know how to get to the data item type that I referred to. Here is what I have. I do not know how to parse the content to pick up the variable. `stocksoup = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GE/key-statistics") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(stocksoup.content, "html.parser")`

Comment: @anjsimmo, thanks for your comment. You are right about the javascript - I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate: Surprisingly, the structure of the Yahoo! Finance page hasn't changed much since a similar question from three years ago. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631386/how-to-understand-this-raw-html-of-yahoo-finance-when-retrieving-data-using-pyt/39635322#39635322) to extract the JSON data from Yahoo finance still works!

Comment: Thanks @anjsimmo, that code works too!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re`/`json` module to extract the data.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GE/key-statistics'

html_text = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r'root\.App\.main = (.*?\});\n', html_text).group(1))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['defaultKeyStatistics']['floatShares'])
```

Prints:

```
{'raw': 8733446536, 'fmt': '8.73B', 'longFmt': '8,733,446,536'}
```